# Retrieve data from external API and pass multiple data to my view

Tags: php, laravel, api

In my controller i have this function

```
public function GetStatusDetails()

{
    $response = Http::get('https://exemple.exemple.com/fr/api/<token>/availability/<Id>/getStatusDetails?format=json');
    $StatusDetails = json_decode($response->body(), true);
    //dd($data);
    return view('ControlmAPI.netvigie', [
        'StatusDetails' => $StatusDetails
    ]);

}

public function GetStatus()

{
    $response = Http::get('https://exemple.exemple.com/fr/api/<token>/availability/<Id>/getStatus?format=json');
    $Status = json_decode($response->body(), true);
    //dd($data);
    return view('ControlmAPI.netvigie', [
        'Status' => $Status
    ]);

}
```

Is not the same call api but when i want to use StatusDetails in my blade i can't but Status i can so my question is how to pass multiple data to my blade and use it separately.

the dd of them is [DD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL5Eb.png) so in my blade i do `{{$Status[0]['status']}}` it work but when i want to do for "StatusDetails" it doesn't but if i do only for "StatusDetails" it works but not for both someone have the solution please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass them as an array

```php
public function GetStatus()

{
    $statusResponse = Http::get('https://exemple.exemple.com/fr/api/<token>/availability/<Id>/getStatus?format=json');
    $statusDetailsResponse = Http::get('https://exemple.exemple.com/fr/api/<token>/availability/<Id>/getStatusDetails?format=json');
    $Status = json_decode($statusResponse->body(), true);
    $StatusDetails = json_decode($statusDetailsResponse->body(), true);

    return view('ControlmAPI.netvigie', [
        'Status' => $Status,
        'StatusDetails' => $StatusDetails,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: All of that is for 1 application of the API if i want to access to the same information but to a different ID of application in my blade how can i do ? Like i want to do that for other application in the same controller is possible ?